# merge two observables array into single observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Observable array `similarIdeasObservable$` and another Observable array being getting from server by like `this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas()`. I want to merge these two Observable arrays without using subscribe. How Can I do this?

I am trying following way

```
 this.similarIdeasObservable$.pipe(concat(this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(this.idea).pipe(
        concatMap(i => i),
        toArray(),
        catchError(error => {
          throw error;
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        })
      )));
```

`concat` is deprecated.

Comment: I think, you can use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to do that

Comment: @R3tep, could you make a example

Comment: You need to explain what does "merge" mean. How will the result observable emit for each emission of single observables? Also concat is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) to merge multiple observable.

e.g.

```js
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

const example = merge(
  similarIdeasObservable$,
  this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(this.idea)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

The idea of how `forkJoin` works is that it requires the input observables (`observableA` and `observableB` on the below example) to be completed, and it will eventually be used to return an observable represented by an array, which consists of the values returned by the input observables.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

const observableA = this.similarIdeasObservable$;
const observableB = this.ideaService.getSimilarIdeas(this.idea);

forkJoin(observableA, observableB);
```

Comment: In newer versions forkJoin with `params args` is obsolete. You should use an array: `forkJoin([observableA, observableB]);`