# Awaiting for two methods that return observables in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs-observables

I have two methods that make api calls and return observables.

```
private method1(): Observable<Home> {
  return homeService.call.get();
}

private method2(): Observable<User> {
  return userService.call.get();
}
```

Then I have the following two methods:

```
private method3(): void {
  this.method1().subscribe();
  this.method2().subscribe();
}
```

and one last one

```
private method4(): void {
 // does things
 this.method3();
}
```

I want the `method4` to wait for the `method3` to finish all is requests in order to proceed, but I have no idea how to achieve it in angular 8. Any tips?

Comment: @webdevius thanks, I will take a look

Comment: You can check this out :) I answered a question similar to that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178820/merge-two-observables-array-into-single-observable-array/57179067#57179067

Comment: I know this was already marked as answered, but I have an example here for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-deborahk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at a term called **flattening observables** - having nested observables. (Unless you care only about the final response - `forkJoin`)

You have variety of operators that can help you achieve what you need. Here are only some of them. Take a look and you will see which of them applies to your code the best way.

[switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) - Has the canceling effect.

[mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) - "This operator is best used when you wish to flatten an inner observable but want to manually control the number of inner subscriptions."

[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) - "This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each."